# Jupyter markdown not working

Tags: markdown, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am trying to display bold words, equations and italic notes on my Jupyter notebook. However, I can only write comments with a '#' symbol and any other attempts to create indentation, bold words and equations are not working.

I need to be able to display Math notations such as:

```
$^1/_2$
${3 \over 4}$
```

Could I be missing a library import or anything similar ?

I'm using Jupyter version 5.0 and Anaconda with Python 3.5

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to convert the cell to a Markdown-type cell. You can do this in command mode by selecting the cell and pressing <kbd>m</kbd> (if the cell is in edit mode with a green border, press <kbd>Esc</kbd> first), or by choosing the "Markdown" type from the dropdown in the center of the menu bar.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, you can start the cell using the cell magic `%%markdown` and then run that cell.

Comment: Using `%%markdown` cell magic I get an error: **UsageError: Cell magic `%%markdown` not found** - I am running JNB 5.6.0 - What version do you use that accepts `%%markdown`?

Comment: It can be found [here](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#cellmagic-markdown). I suppose that it should be available for IPython higher than 6.0.

Comment: I know of course the documentation. My question is why it doesn't work? And I aske you what version do **you** use. Not to suppose.

Comment: I use `ipython` 6.5.0 for `py36`. You can check this `from IPython.core.display import display, Markdown` . The magic is defined in `IPython.core.magics.display`

Comment: Same here. Thank you. I still get "UsageError: Cell magic %%markdown not found". No problem. One can always create a markdown cell ...